# Specify link weight in VivaGraphJS

Tags: javascript, vivagraphjs

How to specify a weight for a link in a VivaGraphJS graph? E.g. I want get a resulting social graph where a married couple is displayed closer than somebody only loosely known.

With the `springLength` I can define a general distance, but nothing that is specific per link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example how to do it: [customLinkLength.html](https://github.com/anvaka/VivaGraphJS/blob/master/demos/other/customLinkLength.html)

Unfortunately there is no easy way to find best force layout arguments, which would suite all kind of graphs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and blame on me, that I didn't found it on your site.